# Probability using a defined sample space.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Given a bag of $5$ different colour marbles: $R, G, B, W, Y$, we need to create a sample space to
study the outcome of when $3$ marbles are picked out of the five marbles in the bag.

The way I approached this, is that since we are creating a sample space for $3$ marbles picked
out of $5$, then there is $\binom53$ ways to make the selection.

Therefore,

$$\begin{align*}
\binom53 &= 10\\
&= \{(RGB), (RGW), (RGY), (RBW), (RBY), (RWY), (GBW), (GBY),\\
&\qquad\qquad(GWY), (BWY)\}
\end{align*}$$

So now that I have my sample space how do I find the probability of a selection using my sample space which include for example $Y$. I know that without the sample space I can use combinatorics to do something like

$$\frac{\binom42}{\binom53}$$

which gives the probability that the selection includes $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me point out a serious notational error: your sample space is fine, but it is a set of $3$-element sets of marbles, **not** a number, so it is **not** equal to $10$. Its **cardinality** is $10$.

The $10$ outcomes in your sample space are all equally likely, so each has probability $\frac1{10}$ of occurring. By actual count there are $6$ outcomes that include $Y$: $(RGY),(RBY),(RWY)$, $(GBY),(GWY)$, and $(BWY)$. Thus, the probability of getting one of them is $6\cdot\frac1{10}=\frac35$. Other problems can be done similarly: just count the outcomes in the event whose probability you wish to compute.

Comment: Oh, thanks. So if the sample spaces wasn't defined than would my approach using combinatorics we correct?

Comment: @Sc4r: Yes, absolutely. (And that’s the way that I’d probably do it, too.)

Comment: If we were to determine the probability of selection including either B or G, does that mean it has to be either one of B or G in the set or does it have to include for both B and G. The way I have it do far is: 6*1/10 = 3/5 this is with either b or g but not both.

Comment: @Sc4r: I would interpret that wording to mean that you want the outcomes that include $B$ or $G$ or both. That’s every outcome except $(RWY)$, so the probability is $\frac9{10}$.

Comment: Thanks for your help Brian, I now understand this :)

Comment: @Sc4r: You’re welcome.